# Push notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

How to push notifications when app is not running?

My code:

```
var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
localNotification.alertBody = "You have received \(Int(msg)) new messages"
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber++
//play a sound
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.alertAction = "View"

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

When my iOS app is closed, he didn't check and show new notifications? Who can help me with this problem?

And Does anyone know if I can start a timer when the app is closed. The timer will check every 5 minutes if there is a new messages en call the function to push a local notification

Comment: Your a not using push notification but local notification, local notification can only be scheduled.

Comment: @rckoenes And Local Notifications can't show when the app is closed?

Comment: Yes they can and should. Have you requested permission to display local notifications?

Comment: @rckoenes I don't know if I have done that. I got the notifications when the app is running. But when the app is closed I didn't get the notifications. Maybe is my place of the code wrong?

Comment: You need to get permission to display localnotification. When you app is on the foreground you should handle the notifications. Please read the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

Comment: @rckoenes Do you know if I can start a timer when the app is closed. The timer will check every 5 minutes if there is a new messages en call the function to push a local notification.

Comment: No, iOS has very strict policy for running in the background. If you set a timmer it will be invalidate when your app goes into the background. If you need to check something on a regular base, then you best option is to use a server with push notification.

Comment: Any one have a link to use a server with push notification ?